# Why all markers show up in the map after entering a query?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on an Android Map application. It usually works fine when I enter a query but sometimes all markers show up unexpectedly.

What correction(s) do I need to make to my code?

This is my code:

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String queryText) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange = " + queryText);
        //Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Change: " + queryText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        addMarkers(queryText);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryText) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit = " + queryText);
        //Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Change: " + queryText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        addMarkers(queryText);

        if (mSearchView != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            if (imm != null) {
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

            mSearchView.clearFocus();
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the situation is when you delete all your query text, the `queryText` becomes `""`. Then all the markers show up because they all contain `""`.

Try to add this code into your methods of the `OnQueryTextListener`:

```
if (!queryText.equals("")) addMarkers(queryText);
```